# nodejs - JSONWebToken does not expire

Tags: node.js, jwt

I implented jsonwebtoken (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) and made two simple functions.
One to create/sign a token with an expiration time and one to verify the token.

I use `jwt.sign('userdata', 'abc', {expiresInSeconds: 1});` to sign the token.
The token should expire after one second, but when I verify the token using `jwt.verify(token, 'abc', function(err, decoded) { }` the var `err` is empty and `decoded` returns `userdata`.

Comment: Are you definitely waiting a second before attempting to decode?

Comment: I just tried it again with the same token I generated before I asked and it is still valid, so yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `jsonwebtoken` library only allows you to sign **Objects**, not Strings. [An issue](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/64) suggests that the spec is a little unclear on this, but the library chose to only operate on Objects.

This code works as expected. Note that I have replaced the string with an Object.

```
token = jwt.sign({ data: 'userdata' }, 'abc', {expiresInSeconds: 1});
setTimeout(function() {
  jwt.verify(token, 'abc', function(err, decoded) {
    console.log(err, decoded);
  })
}, 2000);
```

Output:

```
{ name: 'TokenExpiredError',
  message: 'jwt expired',
  expiredAt: Sun Apr 19 2015 11:08:36 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) }
```